# Can I use my phone to unlock my PC?

Tags: login, mobile-phone

Hey guys am a little lazy and I do not want to type in the password when the login screen shows up. Is there an app available on mobile phone that I can use to save the password there and once I have connected my phone to PC over hotspot or Bluetooth I just click on an unlock button on the app from my phone and it tries to unlock my PC? I am just trying to automate the login process but still maintain the authentication requirements. The opposite side of dynamic lock, allow windows to unlock my device when it detects am close? Is this achievable?

Comment: My Apple Watch can unlock my Mac, don't know if anything else supports this.

Comment: Would really love an app that just unlocks my PC over wifi

Comment: There's already tools that do this. I believe there's also functions built in to Windows that do this. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Tried looking for apps but so far I have seen an app that scans qr code from mobile phone to unlock